# Bluebird promise as callback for promise unaware api

Tags: node.js, promise, passport.js, bluebird

I would like to pass a promise to passport's done callback function. How would i go with this if i use the `bluebird` promise library?

I know there is a promisification topic and there is an `asCallback` and `fromCallback` but i couldn't get the idea from the examples.

```
exports.signup = new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  (req, email, password, done) => {
    ...
    return done(null, false, {type: 'warning', message: 'Email is in use.'})
    ...
  }
);
```

EDIT:

this what i would like to achieve:

```
exports.signup = new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true,
  passportLocalCallback
});

function passportLocalCallback(req, email, password, done) {
  return new Pormise((resolve, reject) => {
    return User.findOneAsync({email: email});
  })
  .then((existingUser) => {
    if (existingUser) {
      resolve([null, false, {type: 'warning', message: 'That email is already taken.'}])
    }
    return User.generateHash(password);
  })
  .then((hash) => {
    return User.createAsync({
      email: email,
      password: hash
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => reject(err));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to work, as Passport requires that `done()` is called with particular arguments (an object representing a user if authentication was successful, or something falsy if not). Can you elaborate what exactly it is you want to do (where is the promise coming from, for instance).

Comment: @robertklep i updated the question, hopefully its more clear now. I'm quite sure this can be done with bluebird promisification utils, but not clear how.

Comment: `new Pormise((resolve, reject) => {
    return User.findOneAsync({email: email});
  })` is wrong for sure. Not only because of the typo, but because you must not return anything from the constructor callback.

Comment: aah i see, so in constructor cb i dont need to use `return` because it will be in the first `then` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get it working with the promisification tools, mostly because Passport also has a valid 3-argument callback situation, which is something that Bluebird doesn't know about (I think).

The only solution I can come up with for the moment:

```
function passportLocalCallback(req, email, password, done) {
  User.findOneAsync({ email : email }).then((existingUser) => {
    if (existingUser) {
      return done(null, false, {type: 'warning', message: 'That email is already taken.'});
    }
    return User.generateHash(password).then( (hash) => {
      return User.createAsync({
        email    : email,
        password : hash
      })
    }).then( (user) => {
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }).catch((err) => done(err));
}
```

**EDIT**: using `asCallback()` will shorten the code a bit, but IMO it's not a whole lot less messy:

```
function passportLocalCallback(req, email, password, done) {
  User.findOneAsync({ email : email }).then((existingUser) => {
    if (existingUser) {
      return [ false, { type: 'warning', message: 'That email is already taken.' } ];
    }
    return User.generateHash(password).then( (hash) => {
      return User.createAsync({
        email    : email,
        password : hash
      })
    });
  }).asCallback(done, { spread : true });
}
```

(untested)

Comment: but that means i will have to mix callback style with promises in many scenarios which i think would make a lot of mess.  i was hoping the use case of `asCallback` is something which meant to solve cases like this. and there is also a spread option for multiple arguments. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html

Comment: @AttilaEgyed I edited my answer to use `asCallback()`